# TFS - how to check in reviewed code, but no later code

Tags: tfs

Every time I've coded a new feature (about once a day), I create a shelve set containing my changes and request a code review of my team lead (of the changes in the shelve set). He's pretty busy and it takes him half a day to a day to do the review. Meanwhile, I've continued coding the next feature, on top of the changes that I asked him to review.

My problem is: How do I then check in the changes that he approved, but not the (unreviewed) changes that I made after I created the shelve set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As MrHinsh says you need to park what your working on and progress the code review check in and then return to what you are doing.

If you are using the the TFS code review then you will be using VS Premium or above, you can therefore use the My work tab to handle this process for you. You can Suspend what you are working on, revert back to your reviewed code, and when that is completed you can then restart the work that you were on.

TFS will shelve your changes and work items for the Suspend, when you then restart the work all of the source and work items will be restored back to the IDE and the IDE will revert back to the state it was in when you paused.

Information on the My Work can be found http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh543900.aspx

Answer (score 2):

There are really two main options for this:

1. You can shelve your new changes and revert. Then retrieve the shelve for the review and checkin. Then retrieve the new work.
2. You can have a seperate workspace that you keep clean of new development for checking in the reviews. Switch to it, get latest, and retrieve the reviewed code. Then check in.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated. I'm pretty new to TFS. 1) With "revert", do you mean untick "Preserve pending changes locally." when I shelve my unreviewed changes? 2) What will it revert to? To the state when I did the previous shelveset or to the state when I did my last check in?